# Discord.py sends an odd message format in randomizing commands

Tags: python, discord.py

Apologies for the confusing title, I didn't know how to describe the problem in one sentence.
Discord.py has been sending messages with punctuation or parenthesis that weren't there in the code, this is happening for several commands and I've tried rearranging variables to no success.
Does anyone know how to fix this
This is my code:

```
        valid_level = random.randint(0,100)
        valid_message =  " you are ",valid_level,"% valid "
        await client.send_message(message.channel,valid_message)
```

Instead of sending " you are (variable generated %) valid", the bot sends " (' you are ', 48, % valid ') " as the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
valid_message =  " you are ",valid_level,"% valid "
```

creates a tuple: `(' you are ', 48, % valid ')`

You need to `str.format`

```
valid_message =  " you are {}% valid ".format(valid_level)
#or
valid_message =  f" you are {valid_level}% valid "
```